# How to get index of selected tab in UITABBAR

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

How to get selected Index of UITabBar item in swift 
I am not talking about **UITabBarController**.

I know i can get using UITabBarItem.tag.

But for me I cannot use tag for selected index because it already used for other purpose. 
Is there any other way i can get index of selected tab in swift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar

UITabBar has 2 properties "items" and "selectedItem", both of type UITabBarItem.

So u can get the index of selected item by getting the index of "selectedItem" in "items".

```
items.index(of: selectedItem)
```